# How can I delete the case comments of others given in my case

Tags: case, permissions, case-comment

I have to delete the comments provided by other users in a case which is owned by me (Myself is the case owner). Is there a way or permission I need to have to delete those comments. I cant find where exactly I can perform this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CaseComment doesn't have separate permissions.

**To delete Case Comments by other, user has to have `Modify All` permission on Case object.**

For more information, refer [Creating and Editing Case Comments on Case Detail Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_comments_create_detail_page.htm&language=en&type=0)

[image: Case comments user permission]